# JDBC looking for old table name

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, jdbc

I'm writing a Spring application and in general it's going quite well. I have a join table for a many-many relationship that I had to rename because of some other bug where join tables that contain one of the names of one of the parent objects apparently can't be looked up properly.

At any rate, I'm creating the table through SQL using flyway like this

```
create table harvest_request_matches (
    harvest_request_id int not null references harvest_request(id),
    matches_id int not null references inventory_item(id)
);
```

and I'm renaming it like this

```
ALTER TABLE "public"."harvest_request_matches" RENAME TO "request_matches";
```

and here's how the table name is being referenced in code

```
//InventoryItem.java

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("matches")
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "request_matches",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "matches_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"
            ), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "harvest_request_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"
            )
    )
    private List<HarvestRequest> requestList;
```

Making a request that references the join table causes this error

```
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
ERROR: relation "harvest_request_matches" does not exist
```

A global search in my project for the offending string `harvest_request_matches` yields only the SQL files I reference above.

---

Any advice is appreciated, my ideal situation would be to have this work with the new name, but I can also revert to the old name if that's not possible (though I can't imagine why it wouldn't be)

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I assume you're using Hibernate (the default JPA implementation in Spring Boot), so I have 'sacrificed' the spring tag to add the hibernate tag.